# Acknowledge button in Slack incoming webhook

Tags: slack, slack-api

I use slack for ticketing system, and need button "Acknowledge" button,
On pressing something like check mark should appear with username indicated (so the action does not do any external call).

I am able to add that button in incoming webhook, 
and wonder is there any out of the box solution for that... if not how to add that logic?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incoming webhooks are meant for simple messages only. Any more complex messages, e.g. including interactive features like buttons should be build with the API methods, e.g. [chat.postMessage](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage).

Note that [interactive messages](https://api.slack.com/interactivity) like buttons always do external calls and require your app to have HTTP endpoint that Slack can call.

And just to be clear: There is "built-in" acknowledge button in the Slack API, but you can easily built one by yourself with the buildings blocks from the API.